# Sort NSMutableArray with Ties

Tags: ios, arrays, macos, sorting

I have an NSMutableArray, containing 4 objects. Each of these objects has a property of type int that is called **score** This array is sorted descending on this property. That much is fine.

Now I'm making a scoreboard, which takes in this array and enumerates through it. Basically I need it to look at the **array.score** property and assign it a rank.

1st - (100 points)
2nd - (90 points)
3rd - (50 points)
4th - (10 points)

But the problem is, when I have ties in score I need it to come out like:

1st - (100 points)
1st - (100 points)
3rd - (60 points)
3rd - (60 points)

Basically, I need tie scores to actually show as ties. Having some trouble wrapping my head around the logic here, seems really simple... but my brain is fried right now trying to figure this out.

Here's what I have (this doesn't work):

```
    // If we have the same score, the rank does not change
int rank = 1;
int rankWithTies = 1;
int previousScore = 0;


NSLog(@"------- PLAYER SCORES ------");
for (PlayerStat *stat in rotatorSorted) {

    if (stat.score < previousScore) {

        NSLog(@"A %i. Player %i - score:%i", rank, stat.playerNumber, stat.score);
        rankWithTies++;


    } else {
        previousScore = stat.score;
        NSLog(@"B %i. Player %i - score:%i", rankWithTies, stat.playerNumber, stat.score);
    }

    rank++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you have a tie, you actually skip lower ranks—that is, if you have a tie for second, your players will be 1st, 2nd, 2nd, and 4th, with nobody getting 3rd. I'd make that happen by doing something like this:

```
NSUInteger rankIgnoringTies = 1;
NSUInteger rankWithTies = 1;
NSUInteger previousScore = NSUIntegerMax;

NSLog(@"------- PLAYER SCORES ------");
for (PlayerStat *stat in rotatorSorted) {
    if(stat.score < previousScore) {
        // This is not a tie, so we should move rankWithTies to the next rank.
        rankWithTies = rankIgnoringTies;
    }

    NSLog(@"%i. Player %i - score:%i", rankWithTies, stat.playerNumber, stat.score);

    previousScore = stat.score;
    rankIgnoringTies++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks got it working! I simply changed the rankWithTies++ to rankWithTies = rank.